# Clear selection of TTTableViewController when view appears

Tags: iphone, cell, selection, three20

I can't seem to find a way to clear a TTTableViewController's selected cell after returning from the previous view. Anyone got any advice?

Comment: You'll have to be more clear about what you mean by 'selected'. Is it highlighted?  Are you doing anything custom like overriding didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTTableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController so you can use the `@property(nonatomic) BOOL clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property and set is to `TRUE`

If this does not work you can always deselect the row with

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.view indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

where self.tableView is your TableView. Putting this line in your `viewWillAppear` should work.

Comment: definitely put in the right direction although I had to replace self.view with self.tableView for TTTableViewController.